# What is Difference state and constructor?

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native.  I want to ask what is the difference between

```
state = {

}
```

and

```
 constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = ''
    }
```

I send data from parent class to child class like  `<child value={} />`

but I could not send data from child to parent ?   I tried to send like this:

```
 <Text onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Parent',{deneme: 'abc'})}  ></Text>
```

in the parent class, I  have

```
state = {
deneme : this.props.navigation.params.deneme
}
```

but it gives me an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, the [class field proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) is just syntactic sugar (syntax made to write / read better) but compiles to the same thing so both versions are essentially equivalent. I would stick with the easier to write:

```
state = {
}
```

For your second question, to 'send data' to your parent component the most common method to do it is have your parent component also pass down a method as a prop where when the child calls that method it sets the state in the parent component to have the 'data' stored in the parent component.

*E.g.:*

So in your parent component you should initialize that state property which will hold the 'data' which you want your children components to send up:

```
state = {
   myData: '' // default it to string, array, object, whatever your 
              // eventual data type would be
}
```

And then have a method set up and passed to your child component(s) that can set the state of this state property:

```
// parent include this method

handleSetData = (myData) => {
   this.setState({ myData: myData });
}

// inside render and your child component pass the method to it
<ChildComponent setData = {this.handleSetData} />


// Child Component, inside your button

<Text onPress={('Some data') => this.props.setData('Some data'})}></Text>
```

That's just an example, but you can pass a dynamic argument to that text on press and that will set the state in your parent component and you can thus use that data however you want in the parent component.